# Why couldn't Doom instantly kill the Fantastic Four?

Tags: marvel, fantastic-four, dr-doom, fantastic-four-2015

In the 2015 "film" *Fantastic Four*, Doom has the ability to instantly kill people.

[image: Doom Hallway 1]

[image: Doom Hallway 2]

However, when he faces the Four, he doesn't use this ability on them. While their powers might protect them, this is never made clear.

Do we know for sure what kept Doom from instantly killing the heroes?

Comment: By the way: "This movie is dumb and makes no sense," while accurate, is not an acceptable answer.

Comment: Since the movie made no sense and was internally inconsistent, I would choose to close this question but I will leave this to the community to decide.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze - What struck me is that the OP gave more thought to this excellent question than the writers gave to the film :-)

Comment: @Valorum : One version of what went down is that the studio stepped in and created their own plotline for Dr. Doom, overwriting a lot of the last third of the film with forced, nonsensical reshoots.

Comment: @praxis - So the Director says. The Studio's take on it is that his management was chaotic and that he would turn up at work "tired and emotional", forcing them to edit and reshoot the crap out of what he'd made.

Comment: @Valorum : Apparently he also trashed his rental house during the filming.

Comment: @Praxis - After watching a few minutes of this film, I wanted to get drunk and break things too.

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Fantastic states it while they are fighting him. I can't remember his exact words, but they were something along the lines of 'we got our powers from the same place as him, we can beat him.'

Also a lot of the death Doom causes seems to be kinetic in nature, either reflecting bullets back or exploding things. This is in contrast to the two cases where he focuses and just kills some one, where it seems to take a lot longer than an instant.